# Is necessary to dispose an object when I serialize it?

Tags: java, serialization

I´m new in Java and I want to know if is necessary to dispose object to free memory when I serialize it? I try to use my serializable object after the serialization and works fine but my goal is don´t get access until desserealize it. Thanks.

```
Poo p = new Poo();
try {
        FileOutputStream g = new FileOutputStream("obj.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(g);
        stream.writeObject(p);
        stream.close();
    }
catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
p.getInfo(); // works
```

Comment: Why do you think that this might be necessary in a general sense?

Comment: To free memory and just use again after desserealization. Make sense?

Comment: Not a bit. You're asking "is it necessary", and the answer is most definitely no. If you have a specific reason to "dispose" of the object (whatever that means in the context of your code), then do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use methods that customize serialisation to invalidate the object (i.e. make the object throw an exception on every call of a non-private method; That way you at least ensure no methods are sucessfully called).

```
public final class Poo implements Serializable {
    private volatile boolean invalid = false;
    public String getInfo() {
         synchronized (this) {
             if (invalid) {
                 throw new IllegalStateException("Object shouldn't be used until deserialized");
             }
         }
         // do something
    }

    // do the same to other methods
    // if necessary Object methods like equals and hashCode too

    private class SerializationProxy implements Serializable {
        private Object readResolve() {
            Poo.this.invalid = false;
            return Poo.this;
        }
    }

    private synchronized Object writeReplace() {
        invalid = true;
        return new SerializationProxy();
    }
}
```

However if you just want to make the memory avaliable, it suffices to set all references to the object to `null`. E.g. If there are no static references to `p`:

```
p = null;
```

Which is automatically done at the end of the scope were you declare `p` (most likely end of the method). Maybe the compiler can even do some optimisation (release object if no longer needed); however I don't know, if the language spec allows this.

#### EDIT

Made `Poo` `final` to prevent inherited classes from overriding & adding methods and ignore the `invalid` field.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**, it is not always necessary to "dispose" of an object after serializing it.

If you have a specific reason for "disposing" of the object (whatever that means in the context of your code), then do so. If you have a question about this specific reason, then improve your question, but your question asks in a general sense, and again, in that sense the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is generation of some bytes based on an object in memory.  You can do something with these bytes like write them to a file, send them over the network, etc.  The original object remains the same.

Disposing of an object to "free up memory" is performed by the garbage collector automatically sometime after the object is no longer accessible to your program.  The best you can do is make sure you are not holding any reference to the object.  It will then be collected.

These are separate and unrelated concepts.